# How do I SUM DISTINCT Rows?

Tags: sql, sum, row, distinct, rows

I'm struggling with a query where I need to SUM DISTINCT Rows.  There has to be a way to do this...  but I'm lost.

Here's what I've got:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Zipcodes.CountyID,
us_co_est2005_allData.PopEstimate2005, 
us_co_est2005_allData.EstimatesBase2000,
users_link_territory.userID
FROM
Zipcodes Inner Join Users_link_territory ON zipcodes.CountyID = 
Users_link_territory.CountyID Inner Join
us_co_est2005_alldata ON zipcodes.FIPS = us_co_est2005_alldata.State AND zipcodes.code
= us_co_est2005_alldata.County
WHERE (users_link_territory.userid = 4)
```

This gives me the 34 rows which provide distinct population numbers for each county belonging to userid4, but how would I get the SUM of PopEstimate2005 and EstimatesBase2000?

Something like (but this isn't a legal query):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Zipcodes.CountyID,
SUM(us_co_est2005_allData.PopEstimate2005) AS Population2005, 
SUM(us_co_est2005_allData.EstimatesBase2000) AS Population2000,
users_link_territory.userID
FROM
Zipcodes Inner Join Users_link_territory ON zipcodes.CountyID = 
Users_link_territory.CountyID Inner Join
us_co_est2005_alldata ON zipcodes.FIPS = us_co_est2005_alldata.State AND zipcodes.code
= us_co_est2005_alldata.County
WHERE (users_link_territory.userid = 4)
GROUP BY users_link_territory.userid
```

Of course, as soon as I add Zipcodes.CountyID to the end of the GroupBy, I'm back with my 34 rows again.

Thanks so much for any help.

Russell Schutte
.
.
.
.
.

After getting the below help - in particular Robb's help - I was able to get what I really wanted - a total of each UserID's population details in a single query:

```
SELECT     SUM(POPESTIMATE2005) AS Expr1, SUM(ESTIMATESBASE2000) AS Expr2, UserID
FROM         (
    SELECT DISTINCT zipcodes.CountyID, us_co_est2005_alldata.POPESTIMATE2005, us_co_est2005_alldata.ESTIMATESBASE2000, users_link_territory.UserID
    FROM          zipcodes INNER JOIN
    users_link_territory ON zipcodes.CountyID = users_link_territory.CountyID INNER JOIN
    us_co_est2005_alldata ON zipcodes.FIPS = us_co_est2005_alldata.STATE AND zipcodes.Code = us_co_est2005_alldata.COUNTY
    ) As FOO
GROUP BY UserID
```

Thanks everyone who contributed!

Russell Schutte

Comment: Format your SQL so it's easier to read, please.

Comment: Just figured out how... thanks Todd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want an overall figure for it try

```
select sum(PopEstimate2005), sum(EstimatesBase2000)
from(
    SELECT  Distinct
        Zipcodes.CountyID, 
        us_co_est2005_allData.PopEstimate2005, 
        us_co_est2005_allData.EstimatesBase2000, 
        users_link_territory.userID 
    FROM 
        Zipcodes Inner Join 
        Users_link_territory ON zipcodes.CountyID = Users_link_territory.CountyID Inner Join 
        us_co_est2005_alldata ON zipcodes.FIPS = us_co_est2005_alldata.State AND zipcodes.code = us_co_est2005_alldata.County 
    WHERE 
        (users_link_territory.userid = 4)
) as foo
```

Comment: Hi Robb - Thanks for the quick reply.  You're almost there... and I figured it out from your reply.  Anyone trying to follow this or look it up later - Simply add the keyword DISTINCT back in to the inner SELECT, before the Zipcodes.CountyID.  I don't know if there's a way to make the GroupBy work, but this is it!  Thank you Robb!

Comment: @user541022 Glad it worked for you, I guess i must have mangled the code slightly while reformatting it, edited to include the missing distinct!

Comment: Thanks Robb...  I had tried doing a subselect like that... but was fouled up when I got the "Incorrect Syntax" message about the last parenthesis.  I never knew to add the "as foo".  That's awesome.  When do I need it?

Comment: @user541022 the `as foo` gives the table an alias, sqlserver throws a wobbly when you dont name your subselects.  A hint you might find keeps rsi at bay is that you can alias any table in your from clause with a shorter name ie `us_co_est2005_alldata as dta` then reference it in your select clause as `dta.popestimate2005`

Answer (score 3):

Use [GROUP](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) BY along with the [SUM()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) and [COUNT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) aggregates.

```
SELECT count(*) as totalRows, Zipcodes.CountyID,
   sum(us_co_est2005_allData.PopEstimate2005) as SumPopEstimate2005, 
   sum(us_co_est2005_allData.EstimatesBase2000) as SumEstimatesBase2000,
  users_link_territory.userID

FROM
  Zipcodes Inner Join Users_link_territory ON zipcodes.CountyID = 
  Users_link_territory.CountyID Inner Join
  us_co_est2005_alldata ON zipcodes.FIPS = us_co_est2005_alldata.State AND zipcodes.code = us_co_est2005_alldata.County

WHERE (users_link_territory.userid = 4)

GROUP BY  Zipcodes.CountyID,users_link_territory.userID
```

Depending on your db server, this will be more efficient than doing a sub-select.

Comment: This doesn't give the final sum - it gives me the same 34 rows I started with - the ones I need to SUM.  :-)   Thanks for helping Byron.

Comment: Actually, just put this in an inner select, then sum the columns from there.

Answer (score 2):

An easy answer is use "group by".  Group by has the same effect with the same fields as distinct, but allows you to use aggregate functions.  You can add a "Having" clause after the group by to filter what records you would like to see.

Comment: Not sure where you suggest the "group by" to go.